In CKEditor5, In a editingDowncast converter, how to update src value a view element at thet?
I want insert url from proment getting error ckeditorerror.ts:108 Uncaught CKEditorError: viewWriter.createContainerElement is not a function
Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-viewWriter.createContainerElement is not a function
editor.model.schema.register( 'customMedia', {
        allowWhere: '$block',
        isObject: true,
        allowAttributes: [ 'src' ]
    });

    // Define how the model is converted to the view
    editor.conversion.for( 'dataDowncast' ).elementToElement({
        model: 'customMedia',
        view: ( modelElement, viewWriter ) => {
            const src = modelElement.getAttribute( 'src' );
            return viewWriter.createContainerElement( 'div', {
                class: 'custom-media',
                'data-src': src
            });
        }
    });

    editor.conversion.for( 'editingDowncast' ).elementToElement({
        model: 'customMedia',
        view: ( modelElement, viewWriter ) => {
            const src = modelElement.getAttribute( 'src' );
            const div = viewWriter.createContainerElement( 'div', {
                class: 'custom-media',
                'data-src': src
            });

            // Make the div a widget
            return toWidget( div, viewWriter );
        }
    });

    editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).elementToElement({
        view: {
            name: 'div',
            classes: 'custom-media'
        },
        model: ( viewElement, modelWriter ) => {
            const src = viewElement.getAttribute( 'data-src' );
            return modelWriter.createElement( 'customMedia', { src } );
        }
    });

    // Add a command to insert custom media
    editor.commands.add( 'insertCustomMedia', new InsertCustomMediaCommand( editor ) );

    // Add the button to the toolbar
    editor.ui.componentFactory.add( 'customMedia', locale => {
        const view = new ButtonView( locale );

        view.set( {
            label: 'Insert Custom Media',
            icon: videoIcon,
            tooltip: true
        });

        // Execute the command when the button is clicked
        view.on( 'execute', () => {
            const src = prompt( 'Media URL' );
            editor.execute( 'insertCustomMedia', { src } );
        });

        return view;
    });

